# How export logs to Opentelemetry with Spring Boot 3 Racing + logback

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry

I'm trying to export logs using [opentelemetry manual instrumentation](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/manual/#log-appenders) with a custom `SdkLoggerProvider` for a Spring Boot 3 + Tracing + but whenever I try to add back `logback appender` suggested in the documentation the headers generated by spring boot disappear from the logs, does anybody knows how to export logs proper for Spring Boot 3 app?

Without [logack appender](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/logback/logback-appender-1.0/library)

```
2023-12-05T22:36:06.055Z DEBUG [payment-service,traceID=30855c52a5c6025aa466bd16a2ec9791,7cf1b551d2c66da6,requestId=c6e2286e-bc42-4b84-8c63-f33604986ddb] 36480 --- [payment-service] [nio-8080-exec-2] [30855c52a5c6025aa466bd16a2ec9791-7cf1b551d2c66da6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/v1/payments?usernameFrom=admina", parameters={masked}
2023-12-05T22:36:06.061Z DEBUG [payment-service,traceID=30855c52a5c6025aa466bd16a2ec9791,7cf1b551d2c66da6,requestId=c6e2286e-bc42-4b84-8c63-f33604986ddb] 36480 --- [payment-service] [nio-8080-exec-2] [30855c52a5c6025aa466bd16a2ec9791-7cf1b551d2c66da6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.springboot.SimpleRestApplication$PaymentController#getAllByUsernameFrom(String)
2023-12-05T22:36:06.079Z  INFO [payment-service,traceID=30855c52a5c6025aa466bd16a2ec9791,7cf1b551d2c66da6,requestId=c6e2286e-bc42-4b84-8c63-f33604986ddb] 36480 --- [payment-service] [nio-8080-exec-2] [30855c52a5c6025aa466bd16a2ec9791-7cf1b551d2c66da6] c.e.springboot.SimpleRestApplication     : Return list of payments
2023-12-05T22:36:06.095Z DEBUG [payment-service,traceID=30855c52a5c6025aa466bd16a2ec9791,7cf1b551d2c66da6,requestId=c6e2286e-bc42-4b84-8c63-f33604986ddb] 36480 --- [payment-service] [nio-8080-exec-2] [30855c52a5c6025aa466bd16a2ec9791-7cf1b551d2c66da6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select u1_0.username,u1_0.active,u1_0.balance,u1_0.locale from tb_user u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
Hibernate: select u1_0.username,u1_0.active,u1_0.balance,u1_0.locale from tb_user u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
```

With logback appender configuration

```
2023-12-05T22:41:02.781Z DEBUG [payment-service,traceID=,,requestId=] 37024 --- [payment-service] [nio-8080-exec-3] [                                                 ] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.example.springboot.SimpleRestApplication$PaymentController#getAllByUsernameFrom(String)
2023-12-05T22:41:02.783Z  INFO [payment-service,traceID=,,requestId=] 37024 --- [payment-service] [nio-8080-exec-3] [                                                 ] c.e.springboot.SimpleRestApplication     : Return list of payments
2023-12-05T22:41:02.792Z DEBUG [payment-service,traceID=,,requestId=] 37024 --- [payment-service] [nio-8080-exec-3] [                                                 ] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select u1_0.username,u1_0.active,u1_0.balance,u1_0.locale from tb_user u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
Hibernate: select u1_0.username,u1_0.active,u1_0.balance,u1_0.locale from tb_user u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
```

Following piece of code and configuration used.

Spring Boot App

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(SimpleRestApplication.class)
            .initializers((ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext>) applicationContext -> applicationContext.registerBean(SdkLoggerProvider.class, () -> {
                ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();

                String endpoint = environment.getProperty("otel.exporter.logs.endpoint", "http://localhost:4317");

                return SdkLoggerProvider.builder()
                        .addLogRecordProcessor(
                                BatchLogRecordProcessor.builder(OtlpGrpcLogRecordExporter.builder().setEndpoint(endpoint).build()).build())
                        .build();
            }))
            .run(args);
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: payment-service
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,info,prometheus
  tracing:
    propagation:
      produce: w3c, b3, b3_multi
      consume: b3, w3c, b3_multi
    baggage:
      remote-fields: requestId
      correlation:
        fields: requestId
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0
  otlp:
    metrics:
      export:
        url: ${OTLP_URL:http://localhost:4318}/v1/metrics
    tracing:
      endpoint: ${OTLP_URL:http://localhost:4318}/v1/traces
  opentelemetry:
    resource-attributes:
      "service.name": ${spring.application.name}
logging:
  pattern:
    level: "%5p [${spring.application.name:},traceID=%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-},requestId=%X{requestId:-}]"
```

logback-spring.xml

```
<appender name="OpenTelemetry"
          class="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.appender.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender">
</appender>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="OpenTelemetry"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</root>
```

Comment: Looks like the console appender's pattern is being mangled. You've included just a snippet of the `logback-spring.xml` file, but its not clear how you're configuring the console appender. Also, I don't see you calling `OpenTelemetryAppender.install(OpenTelemetry)` so its not clear how exactly the appender is getting a ref to your SdkLoggerProvider instance.